# Dealing with Hyphens in a JavaScript Object

Tags: javascript, nonfactors-mvc-grid

I'm using an open-sourced grid library (Nonfactors-MVC-Grid) for a .NET MVC5 application and for whatever reason, the renderer converts snake_case variable names in C# to hyphens in JavaScript.

```
document.addEventListener('rowclick', function (e) {
    //Value in C# will be some_id
    var some_id = e.detail.data.some-id; //debugger displays this
});
```

Obviously, this is a terrible naming convention for JS, but I'm curious if there's an alternative way to capture this variable without having to refactor my naming conventions on the back end.

Comment: You can do `e.detail.data['some-id']`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can also access object property with the bracket getter ( `[ ]` ).
This can be used in your case to access object property that contains hyphens.

```
document.addEventListener('rowclick', function (e) {
    //Value in C# will be some_id
    var some_id = e.detail.data['some-id']; //debugger displays this
});
```

You could also use the same getter to get dynamic property

```
document.addEventListener('rowclick', function (e) {
    //Value in C# will be some_id
    let key = 'some-id';
    var some_id = e.detail.data[key]; //debugger displays this
});
```